# Dyncamically change ribbon button image in Excel ( C#, XML)

Tags: c#, xml, button, vsto, ribbon

I made a customized XML ribbon for Excel in Visual Studio. The thing is that I want to change the ribbon-button images dynamically.

Either when a certain cell value has been changed the image is supposed to change or if a timer ticks.

My problem is that i can't find out how to access my certain button (there will be more than one button). 
I'm very thankful for any help.

Comment: Why the close votes? Seems like a legit question to me (not too broad). The OP could add some code to demonstrate and articulate the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Ribbon XML markup. Declare the getImage callback for the buttons in the XML markup and add a corresponding event handler to the code. Call the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860256.aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861131.aspx) method of the [IRibbonUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) inteface when you need to change the image on ribbon controls. Your callbacks will be called where you can specify new images.

Read more about that (sample code is included) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011(v=office.12).aspx)

Also you may find the following ones helpful:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)